# Issues with npm config & errors installing ganache-cli and truffle

Tags: npm, npm-install, truffle, ganache

I want to install ganache-cli and truffle using npm and am getting two types of errors (see codes pasted below).

1. npm config

If I run the command npm config, I get the following errors. Could that be the reason for the errors in 2.?

```
:~ john$ npm config
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm config set
npm ERR! npm config get []
npm ERR! npm config delete
npm ERR! npm config list [--json]
npm ERR! npm config edit
npm ERR! npm set
npm ERR! npm get []
npm ERR!
npm ERR! alias:
```

2. npm install -g ganache-cli

When I install the `ganache-cli` module, I get the following errors:

```
john$ npm uninstall -g ganache-cli && npm install -g ganache-cli
up to date in 0.036s
/Users/john/.npm-global/bin/ganache-cli -> /Users/john/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/cli.js
```

keccak@1.4.0 install /Users/john/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/node_modules/keccak
npm run rebuild || echo "Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."

keccak@1.4.0 rebuild /Users/john/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/node_modules/keccak
node-gyp rebuild

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/keccak/src/addon.o
../src/addon.cc:37:47: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
unsigned int rate = info[0]->IntegerValue();

`/Users/john/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8.h:2609:3: note: 'IntegerValue' declared here
V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int64_t> IntegerValue(
^
/Users/john/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8config.h:351:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT attribute((warn_unused_result))
^
../src/addon.cc:38:51: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
unsigned int capacity = info[1]->IntegerValue();
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/john/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8.h:2609:3: note: 'IntegerValue' declared here
V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int64_t> IntegerValue(
^
/Users/john/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8config.h:351:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT attribute((warn_unused_result))
^
../src/addon.cc:56:48: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
unsigned char bits = info[0]->IntegerValue();
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/john/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8.h:2609:3: note: 'IntegerValue' declared here
V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int64_t> IntegerValue(
^
/Users/john/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8config.h:351:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT attribute((warn_unused_result))
^
../src/addon.cc:64:43: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
size_t length = info[0]->IntegerValue();
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/john/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8.h:2609:3: note: 'IntegerValue' declared here
V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int64_t> IntegerValue(
^
/Users/john/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8config.h:351:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT attribute((warn_unused_result))
^
../src/addon.cc:75:73: error: no matching member function for call to 'ToObject'
KeccakWrapper* to = Nan::ObjectWrap::Unwrap(info[0]->ToObject());
~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
/Users/john/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8.h:2576:44: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'context', but no arguments were provided
V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal ToObject(
^
/Users/john/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8.h:2590:31: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'isolate', but no arguments were provided
Local ToObject(Isolate* isolate) const);
^
5 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/keccak/src/addon.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/john/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/node_modules/keccak
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! keccak@1.4.0 rebuild: node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the keccak@1.4.0 rebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/john/.npm/_logs/2019-11-24T01_36_55_029Z-debug.log
Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used.

secp256k1@3.7.1 install /Users/john/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/node_modules/secp256k1
npm run rebuild || echo "Secp256k1 bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."

secp256k1@3.7.1 rebuild /Users/john/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/node_modules/secp256k1
node-gyp rebuild

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/addon.o
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/privatekey.o
../src/privatekey.cc:73:3: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
secp256k1_ec_privkey_negate(secp256k1ctx, &private_key[0]);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/privatekey.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/secp256k1-src/src/scalar_impl.h:10:
In file included from ../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:11:
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:36:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_normalize' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_normalize(secp256k1_fe *r);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:39:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_normalize_weak' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_normalize_weak(secp256k1_fe *r);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:42:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_normalize_var' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_normalize_var(secp256k1_fe *r);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:46:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_normalizes_to_zero' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_fe_normalizes_to_zero(secp256k1_fe *r);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:50:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_normalizes_to_zero_var' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_fe_normalizes_to_zero_var(secp256k1_fe *r);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:53:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_set_int' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_set_int(secp256k1_fe *r, int a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:56:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_clear' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_clear(secp256k1_fe *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:59:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_is_zero' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_fe_is_zero(const secp256k1_fe *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:62:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_is_odd' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_fe_is_odd(const secp256k1_fe *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:65:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_equal' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_fe_equal(const secp256k1_fe *a, const secp256k1_fe *b);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:68:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_equal_var' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_fe_equal_var(const secp256k1_fe *a, const secp256k1_fe *b);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:71:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_cmp_var' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_fe_cmp_var(const secp256k1_fe *a, const secp256k1_fe *b);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:74:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_set_b32' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_fe_set_b32(secp256k1_fe *r, const unsigned char *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:77:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_get_b32' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_get_b32(unsigned char *r, const secp256k1_fe *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_negate' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_negate(secp256k1_fe *r, const secp256k1_fe *a, int m);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:85:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_mul_int' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_mul_int(secp256k1_fe *r, int a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:88:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_add' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_add(secp256k1_fe *r, const secp256k1_fe *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:92:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_mul' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_mul(secp256k1_fe *r, const secp256k1_fe *a, const secp256k1_fe * SECP256K1_RESTRICT b);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:96:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_sqr' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_sqr(secp256k1_fe *r, const secp256k1_fe *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:103:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_sqrt' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_fe_sqrt(secp256k1_fe *r, const secp256k1_fe *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:106:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_is_quad_var' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_fe_is_quad_var(const secp256k1_fe *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:110:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_inv' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_inv(secp256k1_fe *r, const secp256k1_fe *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:113:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_inv_var' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_inv_var(secp256k1_fe *r, const secp256k1_fe *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:118:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_inv_all_var' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_inv_all_var(secp256k1_fe *r, const secp256k1_fe *a, size_t len);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:121:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_to_storage' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_to_storage(secp256k1_fe_storage *r, const secp256k1_fe *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:124:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_from_storage' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_from_storage(secp256k1_fe *r, const secp256k1_fe_storage *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:127:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_storage_cmov' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_storage_cmov(secp256k1_fe_storage *r, const secp256k1_fe_storage *a, int flag);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field.h:130:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_cmov' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_cmov(secp256k1_fe *r, const secp256k1_fe *a, int flag);
^
In file included from ../src/privatekey.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/secp256k1-src/src/scalar_impl.h:10:
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:44:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_set_xy' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_ge_set_xy(secp256k1_ge *r, const secp256k1_fe *x, const secp256k1_fe *y);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:50:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_set_xquad' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_ge_set_xquad(secp256k1_ge *r, const secp256k1_fe *x);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:54:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_set_xo_var' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_ge_set_xo_var(secp256k1_ge *r, const secp256k1_fe *x, int odd);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:57:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_is_infinity' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_ge_is_infinity(const secp256k1_ge *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:60:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_is_valid_var' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_ge_is_valid_var(const secp256k1_ge *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:62:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_neg' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_ge_neg(secp256k1_ge *r, const secp256k1_ge *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:65:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_set_gej' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_ge_set_gej(secp256k1_ge *r, secp256k1_gej *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:68:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_set_all_gej_var' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_ge_set_all_gej_var(secp256k1_ge *r, const secp256k1_gej *a, size_t len);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:75:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_globalz_set_table_gej' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_ge_globalz_set_table_gej(size_t len, secp256k1_ge *r, secp256k1_fe *globalz, const secp256k1_gej *a, const secp256k1_fe *zr);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:78:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_set_infinity' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_ge_set_infinity(secp256k1_ge *r);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_set_infinity' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_gej_set_infinity(secp256k1_gej *r);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:84:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_set_ge' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_gej_set_ge(secp256k1_gej *r, const secp256k1_ge *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:87:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_eq_x_var' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_gej_eq_x_var(const secp256k1_fe *x, const secp256k1_gej *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:90:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_neg' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_gej_neg(secp256k1_gej *r, const secp256k1_gej *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:93:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_is_infinity' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_gej_is_infinity(const secp256k1_gej *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:96:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_has_quad_y_var' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_gej_has_quad_y_var(const secp256k1_gej *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_double_nonzero' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_gej_double_nonzero(secp256k1_gej *r, const secp256k1_gej *a, secp256k1_fe *rzr);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:103:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_double_var' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_gej_double_var(secp256k1_gej *r, const secp256k1_gej *a, secp256k1_fe *rzr);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:106:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_add_var' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_gej_add_var(secp256k1_gej *r, const secp256k1_gej *a, const secp256k1_gej *b, secp256k1_fe *rzr);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:109:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_add_ge' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_gej_add_ge(secp256k1_gej *r, const secp256k1_gej *a, const secp256k1_ge *b);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:114:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_add_ge_var' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_gej_add_ge_var(secp256k1_gej *r, const secp256k1_gej *a, const secp256k1_ge *b, secp256k1_fe *rzr);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:117:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_add_zinv_var' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_gej_add_zinv_var(secp256k1_gej *r, const secp256k1_gej *a, const secp256k1_ge *b, const secp256k1_fe *bzinv);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:125:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_clear' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_gej_clear(secp256k1_gej *r);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:128:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_clear' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_ge_clear(secp256k1_ge *r);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:131:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_to_storage' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_ge_to_storage(secp256k1_ge_storage *r, const secp256k1_ge *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:134:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_from_storage' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_ge_from_storage(secp256k1_ge *r, const secp256k1_ge_storage *a);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:137:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_storage_cmov' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_ge_storage_cmov(secp256k1_ge_storage *r, const secp256k1_ge_storage *a, int flag);
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group.h:140:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_rescale' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_gej_rescale(secp256k1_gej *r, const secp256k1_fe *b);
^
In file included from ../src/privatekey.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/secp256k1-src/src/scalar_impl.h:20:
../src/secp256k1-src/src/scalar_4x64_impl.h:83:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_scalar_add' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_scalar_add(secp256k1_scalar *r, const secp256k1_scalar *a, const secp256k1_scalar *b) {
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/scalar_4x64_impl.h:897:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_scalar_shr_int' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_scalar_shr_int(secp256k1_scalar *r, int n) {
^
In file included from ../src/privatekey.cc:4:
../src/secp256k1-src/src/scalar_impl.h:225:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_scalar_inverse_var' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_scalar_inverse_var(secp256k1_scalar *r, const secp256k1_scalar *x) {
^
In file included from ../src/privatekey.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/secp256k1-src/src/scalar_impl.h:20:
../src/secp256k1-src/src/scalar_4x64_impl.h:140:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_scalar_negate' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_scalar_negate(secp256k1_scalar *r, const secp256k1_scalar *a) {
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/scalar_4x64_impl.h:156:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_scalar_is_high' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_scalar_is_high(const secp256k1_scalar *a) {
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/scalar_4x64_impl.h:168:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_scalar_cond_negate' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_scalar_cond_negate(secp256k1_scalar *r, int flag) {
^
63 warnings generated.
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/publickey.o
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/signature.o
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/ecdsa.o
../src/ecdsa.cc:88:3: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
obj->Set(info.GetIsolate()->GetCurrentContext(), Nan::Newv8::String("signature").ToLocalChecked(), COPY_BUFFER(&output[0], 64));
^~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/ecdsa.cc:89:3: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
obj->Set(info.GetIsolate()->GetCurrentContext(), Nan::Newv8::String("recovery").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::Newv8::Number(recid));
^~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/ecdh.o
CC(target) Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/secp256k1-src/src/secp256k1.o
In file included from ../src/secp256k1-src/src/secp256k1.c:11:
../src/secp256k1-src/src/field_impl.h:266:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_fe_inv_all_var' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_fe_inv_all_var(secp256k1_fe *r, const secp256k1_fe *a, size_t len) {
^
In file included from ../src/secp256k1-src/src/secp256k1.c:13:
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group_impl.h:202:13: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ge_set_infinity' [-Wunused-function]
static void secp256k1_ge_set_infinity(secp256k1_ge *r) {
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group_impl.h:691:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_has_quad_y_var' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_gej_has_quad_y_var(const secp256k1_gej *a) {
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/group_impl.h:272:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_gej_is_valid_var' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_gej_is_valid_var(const secp256k1_gej *a) {
^
In file included from ../src/secp256k1-src/src/secp256k1.c:14:
../src/secp256k1-src/src/ecmult_impl.h:1135:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ecmult_multi_var' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_ecmult_multi_var(const secp256k1_ecmult_context *ctx, secp256k1_scratch *scratch, secp256k1_gej *r, const secp256k1_scalar *inp_g_sc, secp256k1_ecmult_multi_callback cb, void ...
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/ecmult_impl.h:669:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ecmult_strauss_batch_single' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_ecmult_strauss_batch_single(const secp256k1_ecmult_context *actx, secp256k1_scratch *scratch, secp256k1_gej *r, const secp256k1_scalar *inp_g_sc, secp256k1_ecmult_multi_callba...
^
../src/secp256k1-src/src/ecmult_impl.h:1042:12: warning: unused function 'secp256k1_ecmult_pippenger_batch_single' [-Wunused-function]
static int secp256k1_ecmult_pippenger_batch_single(const secp256k1_ecmult_context *actx, secp256k1_scratch *scratch, secp256k1_gej *r, const secp256k1_scalar *inp_g_sc, secp256k1_ecmult_multi_call...
^
7 warnings generated.
CC(target) Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/secp256k1-src/contrib/lax_der_parsing.o
CC(target) Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/secp256k1-src/contrib/lax_der_privatekey_parsing.o
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/secp256k1.node

ganache-cli@6.7.0
added 88 packages from 85 contributors in 13.26s</pre>`

Comment: Same issue. are you on OSX Catalina? Looks like the build script is trying to compile addon.cc and generates this error. I'm guessing it's including the wrong header files.

Comment: @Weisel2095 were you able to fix this error? I met the same problem and not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this answer.

Instead of using npm to install ganache-cli, I retried using yarn and it worked.
The same thing happened with truffle where it was not installing properly using npm, but it was installed and working well with yarn.

Comment: That's ok for a development environment, but [not for production](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/blob/develop/UPGRADE-GUIDE.md#user-content-fn-1-901d4c52309a2ce5b7bb9f1a469bebd4). Also, `ganache-cli` is now part of `ganache`. So, `npm install ganache --global`. Your first error is an EUSAGE, meaning you called the command incorrectly, only. You're missing an argument, like 'list', so: `npm config list` should work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I resolved it by doing an `nvm install v14; nvm use v14`.